# I am trying to create trigger for before insert but getting some error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER btinsert
BEFORE INSERT ON sample
  BEGIN
    IF (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI')
          NOT BETWEEN ('08:00' AND '22:00') THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'you may insert'
       ||' into EMPLOYEES table only during '
       ||' normal business hours.'); 
   END IF;
END;
```

but I'm getting an error:

> ERROR at line 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"
>   6.     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'you may insert'
>   7.        ||' into EMPLOYEES table only during '
>   8.        ||' normal business hours.');
>   9.    END IF;
>   10. END;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some missing brackets and excess ones too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER btinsert
BEFORE INSERT ON sample
  BEGIN
    IF (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI') NOT BETWEEN '08:00' AND '22:00') THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'you may insert'
       ||' into EMPLOYEES table only during '
       ||' normal business hours.'); 
   END IF;
END;
/
```